# Can my school monitor what I'm looking at at home? Sophos is installed

Tags: windows, android

yesterday I accidentally searched up a website and misspelled a character and it took me to an obscene website that I was horrified by on my school laptop. I was also on my school account. Can my school see what I looked up?

Comment: There's no way we can tell you what your school might do about it, so I removed that part.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Sophos will have recorded the site. And you likely have other software on the laptop for this purpose.

Comment: Depends on the Sophos products and policies.  This could be tracked at the computer or at the firewall or both.  From the computer side, if the site isn't malicious then you would need web control enabled for it to be reported and even then it would be to be controlled by policy.  You could check this by checking the `Enabled` DWORD under the registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Sophos\Web Intelligence\Web Control`.  This will tell you if web control is even enabled at the client.  The fact you didn't get a block page or a warn suggests there would likely be no alert.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, even with Sophos installed. But unlikely if you were at home and are not having a VPN connection established to your school. But nobody will be able to answer it with a yes or no without doing an analysis of your computer.